# Excel, xml+xsl parsing failed

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

In my company we have an old software that creates xls files starting from xml+xsl. Opening the xml, Excel asks for a confirmation and after displays the result as a standard excel file.

Today it just doesn't work anymore. Nothing has changed, but once opened the xml file and answered to apply the xsl stylesheet, excel just does nothing.

We have uninstalled last office updates without success, thinking the matter was about some bug in the newest release of excel, but this didn't solve the issue. The problem is present both in excel 2010 and 2013, that is on every pc we have available at the moment (we have tried on 3 different pc).

Thank's for any kind of help.

Comment: Have you tried updating the software?

Comment: the software was updated, i have tried without success to uninstall last updates, since it worked until yesterday

Comment: @AxelRichter, please, don't judge too quickly without knowing. The xml are preexistent and was produced by an old software to create pdf. We have just created xsl files to have the conversion in xls instead of pdf, without changing all the infrastructure, for a big company that has abandoned the scope and is just trying to have reports until the natural end of its life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was about the security of the file. We have solved just setting the intranet url in the trusted web site of internet explorer. I really don't know why this thing worked until yesterday. I hope the answer will be useful.